# How to fill spinner from string file in android

Tags: java, android

I am a new application developer. I use `MaterialBetterSpinner`  to displays a set of options for the user. I want to get these options from sting file as `getString`.So I do now:

```
  String[] SPINNER_DATA = {getResources().getString (R.string.Small),getResources().getString (R.string.Big)};

    MaterialBetterSpinner materialBetterSpinner;

  materialBetterSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.material_spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptermatr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewTopic.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, SPINNER_DATA);
        materialBetterSpinner.setAdapter(adaptermatr);
```

But I face this problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

String class:

```
 <resources>
        <string-array name="SPINNER_DATA">
            <string name="Small">صغير</string>
            <string name="Big">كبير</string>
        </string-array>
    </resources>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: plz show the class where String[] SPINNER_DATA declared

Comment: Question has been updated @ShaluTD

Comment: I asked to show the class where the String[] SPINNER_DATA mentioned

Comment: @ShaluTD sorry I  updated it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct your code as below. Move your code to `onCreate()` in your Activity. It will solve your `Nullpointer` issue.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] SPINNER_DATA = getResources().getStringArray(R.array. SPINNER_DATA);            
}
```

Comment: Welcome, bro :)

Answer (score 1):

should not be,

// your string file

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">whatevr</string>


     <string-array name="SPINNER_DATA">
           <string name="Small">صغير</string>
        <string name="Big">كبير</string>
        </string-array>

</resources>




  String[] COUNTRIES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SPINNER_DATA);
```

Comment: Hi brother I get one error :Cannot resolve symbol 'array'

Comment: that's a sample, just copy the <string-aaray part and paste it to string class

Comment: Cannot find array. I don't know why